# How to connect sql server to mysql (xampp)..?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, odbc

I want to connect SQL server to MySQL (XAMPP)? and I am using ODBC driver, I have also attached a screenshot of my problem here:

[image]

In this screenshot when I select database it shows me not responding so what step should I do to solve my problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su1MV.jpg)

I have one more query is what should I fill in these columns, I have also attached these columns screenshot[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su1MV.jpg).

Comment: there is difference in MySQL and SQLServer. You need to tag and use the word carefully in yout question

Comment: You have to select the right port. Please have a look at the screenshot in my answer.

Comment: @Ravi The question is clear as well bro. Coz the reason is, the OP is using SQL Server to connect to MySQL Server. Some kind of double database connectivity I guess.

Comment: I have one more query is, What should I fill in these columns, I have also attached these columns screenshot2 like SSL key, SSL certificate etc in SSL option.

Comment: @Soolie what are you saying ?? double database what is that mean ? And how does this make any sense `using SQL Server to connect to MySQL Server` ???

Comment: @Ravi Sorry for not being clear. The OP wants to connect MS SQL Server with MySQL Server. And the only way it is possible natively is using a bridge, here, ODBC. In ODBC, OP is specifying the source DataBase as MySQL Server, where he gave the Apache port instead of MySQL Port. Kindly map what I said with what OP has posted. Let me know if it is still unclear. This is what I understood. If I am wrong, kindly correct me bro.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the port you are connecting to doesn't have MySQL Running but Apache running there. You have to select the right port. It should be either **8087** or **3306** (default) or **3307**.

You should check for your port here:

[image: my port]

In my case, it's **3306**.

Comment: OP is asking SQLServer not Mysql. I believe, you are aware of difference.

Comment: @Ravi I am very well aware of the differences. The screenshot of OP shows MySQL. Please kindly confirm. Also in XAMPP, it's MySQL and not SQL Server. Kindly look at the image in the OP's question! :)